# Calculate interval between boolean column change

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with measurements of weather here is a simplified version of it:

```
"station_id","measured_at","rainy"
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
"b6b53561-dab5-4b9a-8d28-a7de1e4d1485","2020-01-31 18:35:35.27+00",FALSE
"b6b53561-dab5-4b9a-8d28-a7de1e4d1485","2020-01-31 18:36:33.976+00",FALSE
"b6b53561-dab5-4b9a-8d28-a7de1e4d1485","2020-01-31 18:37:33.864+00",FALSE
"b6b53561-dab5-4b9a-8d28-a7de1e4d1485","2020-01-31 18:38:34.767+00",TRUE
"b6b53561-dab5-4b9a-8d28-a7de1e4d1485","2020-01-31 18:39:36.076+00",TRUE
"b6b53561-dab5-4b9a-8d28-a7de1e4d1485","2020-01-31 18:40:29.776+00",FALSE
"b6b53561-dab5-4b9a-8d28-a7de1e4d1485","2020-01-31 18:41:35.579+00",FALSE
"b6b53561-dab5-4b9a-8d28-a7de1e4d1485","2020-01-31 18:42:34.274+00",TRUE
"b6b53561-dab5-4b9a-8d28-a7de1e4d1485","2020-01-31 18:43:23.842+00",TRUE
"b6b53561-dab5-4b9a-8d28-a7de1e4d1485","2020-01-31 18:44:35.08+00",FALSE
```

and I need to calculate how much time is been sunny. I know I need to use window functions but I'm stuck. Because I need this interval to be calculated in some range for example for last day. I have been able to make a query to this stage.

```sql
SELECT 
    prev.station_id,
    prev.rainy,
    prev.measured_at AS started_at,
    COALESCE(LEAD(prev.measured_at) OVER (ORDER BY prev.measured_at ASC), NOW()) AS ended_at,
    (COALESCE(LEAD(prev.measured_at) OVER (ORDER BY prev.measured_at ASC), NOW()) - prev.measured_at) AS diff
FROM (
    SELECT
        m.station_id,
        m.measured_at,
        m.rainy,
        COALESCE(LEAD(m.rainy) OVER (ORDER BY m.measured_at ASC), m.rainy) AS prev_rainy
    FROM
        z_measurements m
    WHERE m.measured_at >= '2020-01-30T00:00:00.000Z'
    ORDER BY m.measured_at ASC
) prev
WHERE prev.rainy IS DISTINCT FROM prev.prev_rainy
ORDER BY prev.measured_at ASC;
```

this query results in to:

```
"station_id","rainy","started_at","ended_at","diff"
---------------------------------------------------
"b6b53561-dab5-4b9a-8d28-a7de1e4d1485",FALSE,"2020-01-31 18:37:33.864","2020-01-31 18:39:36.076+00","00:02:02.212"
"b6b53561-dab5-4b9a-8d28-a7de1e4d1485",TRUE,"2020-01-31 18:39:36.076","2020-01-31 18:41:35.579+00","00:01:59.503"
"b6b53561-dab5-4b9a-8d28-a7de1e4d1485",FALSE,"2020-01-31 18:41:35.579","2020-01-31 18:43:23.842+00","00:01:48.263"
"b6b53561-dab5-4b9a-8d28-a7de1e4d1485",TRUE,"2020-01-31 18:43:23.842","2020-01-31 21:18:04.89333+00","02:34:41.05133"
```

but if the first lane of this result is `rainy = False` the `start_date` should be the same as one in query `2020-01-30T00:00:00.000Z` (I'm assuming that if it's sunny on the first result it has been sunny for whole time between my range start and this first recorded measurement) and also there is missing the last row because last measured state is sunny. So `started_at` for this last row should be `2020-01-31 18:44:35.08+00` and `end_at` should be `NOW()`.

Can somebody please help me?

I'm using postgresql 12.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t.station_id, t.rainy, t.started_at, t.ended_at, t.ended_at - t.started_at AS diff
FROM (
    SELECT
        prev.station_id,
        prev.rainy,
        CASE
            WHEN LAG(prev.measured_at) OVER measured_at_by_station_id IS NULL THEN '2020-01-30T00:00:00.000Z'
            ELSE prev.measured_at
        END AS started_at,
        LEAD(prev.measured_at, 1, NOW()) OVER measured_at_by_station_id AS ended_at
    FROM (
        SELECT
            m.station_id,
            m.measured_at,
            m.rainy,
            LAG(m.rainy, 1, NOT(m.rainy)) OVER (PARTITION BY m.station_id ORDER BY m.measured_at ASC) AS prev_rainy
        FROM z_measurements m
        WHERE m.measured_at >= '2020-01-30T00:00:00.000Z'
        ORDER BY m.station_id ASC, m.measured_at ASC
    ) prev
    WHERE prev.rainy IS DISTINCT FROM prev.prev_rainy
    WINDOW measured_at_by_station_id AS (PARTITION BY prev.station_id ORDER BY prev.measured_at ASC)
) t
ORDER BY t.station_id ASC, t.started_at ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps and islands problem, where you want to group together series of adjacent records.

Here is one way to solve it using `row_number()` over two different partitions: the difference between the ranks give you the group each record belong to, that you can use to aggregate the resultset.

```
select
    station_id,
    rainy,
    min(measured_at) started_at,
    max(measured_at) ended_at,
    max(measured_at) - min(measured_at) diff
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by station_id order by measured_at) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by station_id, rainy order by measured_at) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by station_id, rainy, rn1 - rn2
order by station_id, started_at
```